# Get return value of process by PID

Tags: kill, pid

If I have the PID of a process that was killed, how might I get the return status of the process?

I am particularly interested to know if the return status was 143 (`kill`) or 137 (`kill -9`) as I don't know what is killing the process. It is a Python script being run from a PHP script on a server that I don't have root access for. The Python script runs for a few minutes, but PHP is limited to running for 30 seconds. PHP has facility to get the return status with `exec()` however that won't work if the PHP script has timed out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly determined by (the default) `php.ini` or equivalent setting:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

TLDR: if you are certain that PHP is really exiting first, and something is killing your script, then you can either use [daemon](http://libslack.org/daemon/) to wrap and monitor the Python process (in non-restarting mode, i.e. without `--respawn`), or add [signal handers](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/signal.html) to the Python script.

In general, if you are able to run a shell as the userid of the script, then you should be able to `strace` or `truss` the process, e.g. on linux you can do this reasonably effectively:

```
 $ sleep 60 &
 [1] 10873
 $ strace -e trace=signal,process  -p $!
 Process 10873 attached - interrupt to quit
 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
 Process 10873 detached
```

The `sleep` process was terminated with a `kill -9` from another terminal. `kill -9` would not be common though, since a process would not be able to trap this and cleanly exit.

To monitor with `daemon` use a variation on:

```
daemon -i --errlog=/tmp/mypy.log -- /usr/bin/python [...]
```

This will log any signal related termination. Add `--dbglog` and `--debug=2` if you want to log every exit regardless.

As noted elsewhere if the process has already terminated, it's gone. Only the parent (or init) would have been able to obtain its exit code, and unless it was logged (possibly using process accounting or auditing), the exit code is lost.

Internally for timeout handling on *nix platforms, PHP sets up a `SIGALARM` or `SIGPROF`  with the specified timeout. That signal handler simply calls the internal `zend_error()` function. It does however also call any [registered callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and [error handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), which may be of use to you.

If the default error handler kicks in, the PHP exit code will be, I believe, 255, since a timeout is an `E_ERROR`.

Also note, the convention of an exit code as 128+N, where N is the signal number, is due to the behaviour of certain shells (including `bash`) and many APIs. The actual process exit code after a signal is system dependent. It is *probably* just the signal number, this is generally the case on Linux. The `wait()` group of system calls provide better details of the process exit. PHP follows the shell convention, e.g. if you are using `popen()` and `pclose()` you will see 128+N as the exit code when a signal terminated the process.

Another consideration here is the behaviour of PHP time limits, if you check the [`set_time_limit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) documentation you will see

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive `max_execution_time` only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

You can prove this with a short script:

```
<?php
# for (;;);
$exe="sleep 20";
print "exit code: " . pclose(popen($exe, 'r'));
?>
```

Invoke with `time php -d max_execution_time=5 -f  sleep3.php`.
The script will run for 20 seconds, there will be no error. If you kill the sleep process, e.g. `kill -USR1 $(pgrep sleep)` in another terminal, you will see an exit code of 138 (128+SIGUSR1).

If you uncomment the infinite `for(;;)` loop, the script will terminate after 5 seconds.

Comment: The status reported to the parent process (via the [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) system call family) encodes the 8-bit value passed to `_exit` if the process exited normally, the signal number if the process was killed by a signal, and a few more flags. I don't know how PHP reports it, but typically it wouldn't be “just the signal number”, it would be the signal number bit-shifted and with other bits set.

Answer (score 2):

A process that has been killed no longer exists on the system. In fact, on a busy host, there's a pretty good chance that a long-running and since killed process has had its PID reused by some other process, so you'd end up looking at something totally unrelated!

*When a process gets killed, **it** does not return anything. It simply ceases to exist.* This in contrast to a catchable signal such as HUP or USR1, which the process *can* (but does not necessarily) catch and handle in any way it sees fit (including exiting with a defined exit code).

If you have sufficient access, you might be able to install some sort of library or kernel module which intercepts and records the syscalls which ultimately result in the process in question receiving a signal, but it does seem easier to [as pjc50 suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87759/2465) just **add a wrapper script** and record the exit status somewhere.

An alternative would be to not make the user wait but rather **move to an asynchronous architecture** for whatever you are doing that takes so long to complete.

Comment: “When a process gets killed, it does not return anything.” True but irrelevant. When a process gets killed, the signal number is reported over the same channel that reports the exit status for a process that exits normally.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure whether that's irrelevant, actually. (It might be, but not necessarily for the reason you are implying.) Note the phrasing of the question: *"If I have the PID of **a process that was killed,** how might I get the return status of the process?"* So the process no longer exists by the time the OP wants its return status, meaning there's nothing left to hook on to or query. The past tense form "was" makes this a very different question than, say, "how can I get the return value of a process that runs longer than the program invoking it?".

Comment: The “return status” of a process can mean three different things: the 8-bit value passed to `_exit` (only if the process exited normally), the status reported by `wait` and family (which encodes the value passed to `exit` if the process exited normally, the signal number if the process was killed by a signal, and some more flags), or the condensed 8-bit status reported by shells in `$?` where signals are converted to values above 128. By the numbers in the question, the asker was talking about `$?`, but needs to be educated about how it's made.

Answer (score 1):

You want [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid), but I don't know if that's available in PHP. Don't forget to add WNOHANG if you don't want it to block. However, that only works if the PID is of a child of the calling process.

It might be easiest to put a wrapper script around the python script that records its termination status in a log file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the exit status if PHP is no longer the parent process is simple. Wrap the Python script in a BASH script to record the exit status in a file. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
false # false is a program that always has an exit status of 1.
echo $? > exit_status.log
```

Will put '1' into `exit_status.log`. Just replace `false` with your actual Python script.

---

Triggering the script to run as disowned non-blocking process in the background from PHP is more difficult. Consider triggering the process with a Cron schedule and avoid PHP all-together!

Otherwise, a possible solution is to call the script using `at`. Here is a complete solution:

From PHP call:

```
<?php
exec("at -f commands now");
```

In the file, `commands`:

```
sleep 10 # Do nothing for 10 seconds
false # Return status 1
echo $? > exit_status.log
```

If you do not have root access and `at` is not installed, then  compile it locally into your home directory, by using a something like `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local`. Otherwise, ask the administrator to install the package.

Further reading: [`man at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at), [`man cron`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron)

Comment: Wouldn't `atd` still need to be running outside of the web server's process and security context, though?

Comment: Thank you. It was difficult to pick an 'accepted' answer here!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

From PHP:

```
exec("./wrapper.sh");
```

In `wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./wrapperlogger.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

In `wrapperlogger.sh`:

```
./yourPythonScript
echo $? > exit_status.log
```

The first wrapper backgrounds the process. The second wrapper monitors for the exit code and logs it to a file. Be careful that this script will overwrite the same log file each time it is executed.

Comment: Thank you. It was difficult to pick an 'accepted' answer here!